# Serving different / dynamic content based on user's IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, ip

Suppose my IP address is x.x.x.1 (NYC), and yours is x.x.x.2 (Los Angeles).

I visit mydomain.com/stuff, and I see threads about "stuff" but only in the NYC area (based on my IP address).  You visit mydomain.com/stuff and you see threads about "stuff" but only in the Los Angeles area (based on your IP address).

General Question: Using Ruby on Rails, how can I make the same URL, mydomain.com/stuff, show dynamic content based on a visitor's IP address?  For example, I'm aware of enterprise software, like Monetate, which allows a website to change images/text on a website to show jackets to NYC IP addresses but swimwear to Hawaii IP addresses.

My current approach is as follows:  My "post" model has fields: "user_id", "content", "ip", "city".  I will use geokit-gem to populate the "city" field from the "ip" address. From there, I can read a visitor's IP address, deduce their city, and filter the on-page content to match the visitor's city.  But...

Specific Questions: How do I (1) obtain the IP address for a visitor, and (2) pass that IP address from the visitor through the routes and into a controller that manages the "show" action, such that I can filter based on city?

Points awarded for answers to questions #1-#2 above, identifying flaws in my general approach, and outlining your own approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IP with: **request.remote_ip**

And you can use Geocoder https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Check this RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

The flow seems good to me, you can filter your posts by the city, and also you can filter by nearby locations.